How to send a synchronous HTTPS POST request from a NodeJS backend to an external resource through a proxy
I have a NodeJS program that instantiates an Express server, accepts a request on a /make_a_test_api_call, and sends an HTTPS request to an external REST API:
"use strict";

const express = require("express");
const https = require('https');
const querystring = require('querystring');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

(
    async () => {
        const app = express();
        app.use(express.json());
        app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


    app.use('/make_a_test_api_call', async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            // Custom headers for the token request
            const customHeaders = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Authorization': 'Basic base64encoded',
            };

            
            const options = {
                hostname: 'rest.service.com',
                port: 443,
                path: '/path/path/token',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: customHeaders,
                rejectUnauthorized: false
                
                /*
                ,
                agent: new https.Agent({
                    host: 'proxy.domain.bz',
                    port: 8443

                }) */
            };
    
        
            const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
                console.log(`request statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
                
                // Buffer to store the response data
                let responseData = '';
    
                // Listen for data chunks in the response
                res.on('data', (data) => {
                    responseData += data;
                });
    
                // Once the response is complete
                res.on('end', () => {
                    console.log('response:', responseData);
                    res.status(res.statusCode).send(responseData); // Send the response back to the client
                });
            });
    
            // Handle errors during the request
            req.on('error', (error) => {
                console.error('request error:', error);
                res.status(500).send({ error: 'Internal server error' }); // Send an error response to the client
            });
    
            // Request body for the request
            const requestBody = {
                param_name: "param_value"
            };
    
            // Write the request body to the request
            req.write(querystring.stringify(requestBody));
            req.end(); // End the request
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            res.status(500).send({ error: 'Internal server error' }); // Send an error response to the client
        }
    });

    const server = app.listen(port, () => console.info(`app is listing at ${port}`));
    server.on("error", error => console.error(error.stack));
}
)();

The above code works as expected. The issue is that this program needs to run behind a proxy. When enabling the proxy (in the above example it is commented out), the following error occurs:
Error: write EPROTO F86A0000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:

I've tried using port 8080 for the proxy, the IP address of the proxy, and the same issue occurs. I also know that the proxy works, because i have an identical Java8 program that is able to send the same request and receive response through the same proxy, on the same machine.
Are there additional parameters for TLS settings that i could specify in the https.Agent instantiation ?  Are there alternative NodeJS libraries that i could rely on to send a request ?
